# Youtube search command doesnt work (Discord.py)

Tags: python, pycharm, discord.py

I have made youtube search command in discord.py but for some reason the bot only sends main page of youtube but not the term i want to search.

[image]

My code:

```
@bot.command()
@commands.cooldown(1, 60.00, commands.BucketType.guild)
async def yt(msg, *, search):
    query_string = urllib.parse.urlencode({
        "search_query": search
    })
    html_content = urllib.request.urlopen(
        "http://www.youtube.com/results?" + query_string
    )
    search_results = re.findall(r"watch\?v=(\S{11})", html_content.read().decode())
    await msg.send("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v" + search_results[0])
```

Comment: Cus you forgot the `=` in your message. It should be `await msg.send("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + search_results[0])
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this:

```py
await msg.send("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v" + search_results[0])
```

to this:

```py
await msg.send("http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=" + search_results[0])
```